# Codeception stub method in for

Tags: php, unit-testing, codeception

Is it possible to mock/stub a method in a for statement using Codeception?
I know that in .net, using Moq you can use SetupSequence(), but I haven't been able to find anything related in Codeception.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After searching a lot I found the resolution:

```
<?php
$user = Stub::make('User', array('getName' => Stub::consecutive('david', 'emma', 'sam', 'amy')));
$user->getName(); //david
$user->getName(); //emma
$user->getName(); //sam
$user->getName(); //amy
?>
```